Single view for multiple paths via URL kwargs
I'm building a simple API listing various plants. Currently, it's limited to filter via a single field like common name, species, etc.
My urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('project/family=<str:family>/', views.SpeciesDetail_family.as_view(), name='family'),
    path('project/species=<str:species>/', views.SpeciesDetail_species.as_view(), name='species')
]

And views.py
class SpeciesDetail_species(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpeciesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Species.objects.filter()
        species = self.kwargs['species']
        if species is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(species__iexact=species)
        return queryset

class SpeciesDetail_family(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpeciesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Species.objects.all()
        family = self.kwargs['family']
        if family is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(family__iexact=family)
        return queryset

How can I create a single view for these two paths? So, I just need to parameterize the lookup field (can be family, species, etc.) from the URL like /project/species=PlantSpecies/ or /project/family=PlantFamily/.
If I add kwargs to the path like path('project/family=<str:family>/', views.SpeciesDetail_family.as_view(), {'lu_field':'family'}, name='family'), how can I access lu_field in the views?

Take a look at the code below see if it works the way you want :
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Species
from .serializers import SpeciesSerializer

class SpeciesDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpeciesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Species.objects.all()
        # Access dynamic lookup field and value from kwargs
        lu_field = self.kwargs.get('lu_field')
        lu_value = self.kwargs.get('lu_value')

        # Filter the queryset dynamically
        if lu_field and lu_value:
            filter_kwargs = {f"{lu_field}__iexact": lu_value}
            queryset = queryset.filter(**filter_kwargs)

        return queryset


and here is the urls:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('project/<str:lu_field>=<str:lu_value>/', views.SpeciesDetail.as_view(), name='species_detail'),
]



I would strongly advise not to do this, since it allows arbitrary filtering. You thus could work with project/author__secret__lte=somestring/ to start binary searching on the secret of a user.

You can redirect both to the same view, and thus work with:
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'project/family=<str:value>/',
        views.SpeciesDetailView.as_view(),
        kwargs={'search_by': 'family'},
        name='family',
    ),
    path(
        'project/species=<str:value>/',
        views.SpeciesDetailView.as_view(),
        kwargs={'search_by': 'species'},
        name='species',
    ),
]
and let the view inspect self.kwargs['search_by']:
from django.db.models import Q


class SpeciesDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpeciesSerializer
    queryset = Species.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(
                Q((f'{self.kwargs["search_by"]}__iexact', self.kwargs['species']))
            )
        )
I would strongly advise not to allow filtering on arbitrary fields, since this can expose sensitive data by a hacker performing binary search on the secret.
Another option is, as @Abdul Aziz Barkat says in his comment, you can use an attribute and specify it in the .as_view(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Q


class SpeciesDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpeciesSerializer
    queryset = Species.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(Q((f'{self.search_by}__iexact', self.kwargs['species'])))
        )
and inject this as:
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'project/family=<str:value>/',
        views.SpeciesDetailView.as_view(search_by='family'),
        name='family',
    ),
    path(
        'project/species=<str:value>/',
        views.SpeciesDetailView.as_view(search_by='species'),
        name='species',
    ),
]

It might make more sense to pass search_by as initkwargs to as_view. Would be a bit more difficult for someone to accidentally expose it as a kwarg coming from the URL.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, I've added this to the answer.
